# Spring-ws VS Apache cxf VS Apache Axis2 VS Metro

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf, apache-axis, spring-ws

I need to create soap web service. I already have wsdl and interface and implementation (as pojo).

I am now choosing between subj.
I need frame work that will:

- Work as servlet in servlet container
- Require only one servlet mapping in my web.xml
- Have good spring integration (because my service implementation is spring bean)
- No require me to add annotations. I do not have annotations on my interface or implementation.
- Spring-ws: Looks cool, but as far as I understood it forces me to deal with XML directly which I do not want to do. I want framework to deserialize message and pass it as parameter to my POJO.
- Apache cxf is powerful and has spring integration, but if I use Jax-WS frontend for it I will have to use annotations, and I do not want to touch my POJO. What about simple front-end?
- Metro is Jax-WS RI, so it depends on annotations heavily.

Axis2 seems to be my choice. What would you choose?

---

Just wanna tell what I am trying to do:
Our app connects to remote service using SOAP. They gave us WSDL, we've generated proxy classes and DTO and all this stuff is packed in jar and stored in VCS. Now I need to write emulation for this web service. And I do not want to generate new DTO.

Answer (score 2):

I think Spring WS would be a good fit for you given your requirements.  You do not need to deal directly with the XML.  Spring will serialize/deserialize many types of objects including all of your data transfer objects.  They should just be annotated JAXB entities.  Check out this information: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#d5e1063

If you already have a WSDL you can generate your DTO objects from that WSDL.  There are several tools that do this including most IDE's.

Comment: Thanks but I already have DTO and they are not jaxb annotated:) Can I make Spring-WS use them or should I generate new?

Comment: Do you not have access to the source so you can annotate them now?  Do they match your WSDL?  An alternative would be to generate DTO objects from the WSDL and then map those objects to your already existing classes, though that's a lot of extra code if you don't need it.

Comment: Yes, they match. I do not have access to the source code. Looks like I need to explain my situation, I will edit my original post, ok?

Comment: Using spring you can use different marshallers.  Check out the castor marshaller, I haven't used it personally but I don't think it needs the annotations like JAXB does, it might just work for you.  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html#oxm-castor

Comment: But there is no castor in list of possible marshallers/unmarshallers. Only OXM exists: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html#d5e1063. Anyway, that is about DTO. And what about services?  How could I configure spring to find my endpoint if it has not annotation? Marshaller is parameter of "sws:annotation-driven" tag but I do not want to jave annotation-driven code. I totally lost:(

Comment: Oh, I got it! Castor is OXM implementation! I am sorry. But I still can't get about annotation driven.